# Is there a law of large number for weighted sum of independent random variables

Tags: probability, law-of-large-numbers

I have the following sequence $\{Y_n\}$ of random variables defined as $$Y_n=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a^{k-1}X_k}{\sum_{k=1}^{n}a^{k-1}}$$ where $\{X_n\}$ is a sequence of i.i.d. random variables.

> My question is, is there any weak or strong law of large numbers that says what $Y_n$ is going to converge to, if at all it converges?

I can understand that in general the statement $Y_n\stackrel{p}{\to}\mathbb{E}X$ is incorrect. An illustration of this fact can be given by taking $X_n$'s as i.i.d standard normal random variables, which shows that $Y_n\stackrel{a.s.}{\to}Y$ where $Y\sim \mathcal{N}\left(0,\frac{1-a}{1+a}\right)$ with the assumption that $|a|<1$. But I am unable to get the limit in general. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why $a^{k-1}$ and not $a^k$? (just a detail, not that it matters)

Comment: You can use $a^k$ if you wish, doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume that $\Bbb E|X_1|<\infty$.

**1.** If $|a|<1$ then the random series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a^{k-1}X_k$ converges in $L^1$, hence in probability, hence a.s. (by a theorem of P. Lévy). Consequently $Y_n$ converges a.s to $(1-a)\sum_{k=1}^\infty a^{k-1}X_k$.

**2.** If $|a|>1$ then $Y_n=(1-a^{-1})\sum_{k=1}^n (a^{-1})^{k-1}X_{n-k+1}$, which has the same distribution as $(1-a^{-1})\sum_{k=1}^n (a^{-1})^{k-1}X_{k}$, which converges in distribution to $(1-a^{-1})\sum_{k=1}^\infty (a^{-1})^{k-1}X_{k}$, by the analysis for **1.**

Comment: Okay. Can I get a distribution of the converging series?

Comment: @Sam It depends on distribution of $X$ and $a$. You can easily find all cumulants and write down characteristic function of $Y$, but unless $X$ is normal, it doesn't seem to lead to a easy simplification.

Comment: And what happens if the weights $a$ are not constants but instead are positive random variables  $A_k >0$?  Does the weighted sum $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n A_k X_k / A_n$ with $A_n = \sum_{k=1}^n A_k$ converge almost surely to some $S$ and what does this $S$ equal to ? Thank you